# Cannot query nested document's _id (other fields work)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to find all documents where `vendor._id` has a certain value. Below is the code, I tried, but it returns nothing.

```
let name = sampleData.name, _id = sampleData._id
Product.find({"vendor._id":ObjectID(_id)}).then((products) => {
  //returns empty array
})
```

With the same method I tried to query a different field and it works. But I want to query with `_id` because other fields could vary with time.

```
Product.find({"vendor.name":name}).then((products) => {
  //returns all documents that satisfy the condition.
})
```

Below is a sample document which I want to `find`

```
{
"status" : "active",
"connectedFarms" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "5c412c62bf8a6602f04ae0bf",
        "status" : "inActive",
        "margin" : 10,
        "price" : 55
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "5c4567bcb3845b0536a4d92e",
        "status" : "inActive",
        "margin" : 20,
        "price" : 60
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "5c4567c4b3845b0536a4d931",
        "status" : "active",
        "margin" : 7,
        "price" : 53.5
    }
],
"vendor" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3fcc0c7657ee02ac24bc21"),
    "name" : "manna"
}
}
```

And here is the schema for this document.

```
let ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  vendor:{_id:String, name:String},
  connectedFarms:[{_id:String, name:String, status:String, price:Number, margin:Number}],
  status:{
    type:String,
    trim: true,
    minlength:1
  }
});
```

Comment: You have taken the field `vendor` as a string in the schema. Try to change it to `ObjectId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a different approach on this, and make vendor its own schema. Mongoose does not allow you to nest schemas, so you cannot make the vendor._id a true ObjectID.

**Vendor Schema**

```js
const VendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: string
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vendor', VendorSchema);
```

**Product Schema**

```js
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  vendor: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectID,
    ref: 'Vendor'
  },
  connectedFarms: [{
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    status: String,
    price: Number,
    margin: Number
  }],
  status: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Now when you want to query a product based on the vendors _id, it's very simple! All you need to do is supply the _id of the vendor in the query. *NOTE: There is no reason to convert the _id to an ObjectID in the query, as mongoose accepts strings and converts them later on.*

**Query**

```
const vendorID = myVendor._id;
Product.find({ vendor: vendorID })
.then((products) => {
  // Do something with the found products
});
```

That's it! Much simpler to do, and much cleaner in the database. The vendor field is now easier to reference. You also have the ability to get the full vendor object in a query if desired by populating in the query. The difference is, the population will return the vendor name and _id, rather than just the _id. To do this, run the following:

```
Product.find({ vendor: vendorID })
.populate('vendor')
.then((products) => {
  // Do something with the populated found products
});
```

Comment: Thank u so much for such detailed solution! It solved my problem :)